# Thread safe InetAddress.isReachable()

Tags: java, networking, ping

In my Java application I need to get the ping of multiple connections at once, I have tried using a thread for each connection and measuring the response time but they don't all seem to be correct.

Is there a thread safe way to measure the ping/response time of a connection? I am currently using:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        someInetAddress.isReachable(5000);
        long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }
});
```

However timeTaken doesn't seem to be correct as users with 150 ping are getting 5000 (probably more because it seems to have timed out)

Help is appreciated!
Keir

Edit: Okay found out that its due to Port 7 being closed for some people, is there any other way to ping them without them having to have Port 7 closed?

Comment: Are all users timing out?

Comment: do you have to share `someInetAddress` between all the threads?

Comment: Firewalls? Do clients allow for ICMP Ping and/or TCP Port 7 (Echo)?

Comment: @ChrisCooney Nope, it works fine for some users.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Nope, each someInetAddress is unique for each thread

Comment: @Fildor Good point, I'll check

Comment: @Fildor my ports(sorry) exactly.

Comment: @Fildor You were right, check out my edit

Answer (score 1):

The `isReachable()` method works by trying to connect to TCP port 7 (echo). It doens't actually care whether port 7 is closed or not. All it cares about is whether there is a response of any kind to the connect. A `ConnectException` rates as `isReachable = true`, and it should take about the same amount of time as a successful connection, maybe even quicker. A connect timeout, host not reachable, etc, rate as `false`.

The method is advertised to use ICMP in very limited circumstances: you aren't on Windows and you have root privilege. In practice this never applies.